# Find and add an array with empty string to multidimensional arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist

After a few years working with Swift, I am a bit confused with simple Java operations.

I have an ArrayList, something like this

```
[[],["1","2","3","4"],[],["5","6","7","8"]]
```

I want to iterate through the list and remove any elements that equal [""]. Then, I want to insert this element in the list to be returned, when needed.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getWaypointCoordinates(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> flightplan)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> finalArray = new ArrayList<>();

        // Save all coordinates into one array
        for (int i=0; i<flightplan.size(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList<String> currentPoint = flightplan.get(i);
            if (currentPoint != [""])
            {
                String lat = currentPoint.get(3);
                String lng = currentPoint.get(4);
                ArrayList<String> currentArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                currentArray.set(0, lat);
                currentArray.set(1, lng);
                finalArray.add(currentArray);
            }
            else
            {
                finalArray.add([""]);
            }
        }

        return finalArray;
    }
```

Two lines give errors:

**if (currentPoint != [""])**

**finalArray.add([""])**

How is this implemented in Java?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks to other people's help, this seem to work now:

```
public ArrayList<List<String>> getWaypointCoordinates(ArrayList<List<String>> flightplan)
    {
        ArrayList<List<String>> finalArray = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        // Save all coordinates into one array
        for (int i=0; i<flightplan.size(); i++)
        {
            List<String> currentPoint = flightplan.get(i);
            if ((currentPoint.size() > 1) && (!currentPoint.get(0).equals("")))
            {
                String lat = currentPoint.get(3);
                String lng = currentPoint.get(4);
                ArrayList<String> currentArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                currentArray.set(0, lat);
                currentArray.set(1, lng);
                finalArray.add(currentArray);
            }
            else
            {
                //finalArray.add([""]);
                finalArray.add(Arrays.asList(""));
            }
        }

        return finalArray;
    }
```

Comment: I think you want (currentPoint.size() > 1) && (!currentPoint.get( 0 ).equals("")) for your if statement.

Comment: Why don't you try to use `HashMap` insted `ArrayList` ?

Comment: Jason. Thank you. The if statement works and does make sense. What about adding an element with an empty String?

Comment: Gürtuğ. It would be a good alternative, but too much code would have to be changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That errors are just about the brackets there, in java `""` is a `String` that holds nothing in it and you just need to write like this:

```
if (currentPoint != "")

finalArray.add("")
```

But when you do this, it will not work for comparison in `if-statement`. Because in java, `String` is not a primitive type variable which can be compared using `==, !=, <, >, >=, <=` operators. It is a class type variable can act like what it needed to be but when you need to compare `Strings`, you need to use different a method. Examples:

```
String s = "";
String s2 = "so";
String s3 = "";
boolean b;

b = s.equals(s2);
System.out.println(b);
//Will give you false.

b = s.equals(s3);
System.out.println(b);
//Will give you true.
```

The main reason that `==` operator don't work on this situation is it tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object) while `.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

EDIT

When you first create `finalArray` you initialize it as `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`. That's why it won't work when you try to add it a `String` like `""`.

Comment: `finalArray.add("");` not working. `finalArray.add(Arrays.asList(""));` not working...

Comment: I recently tried that and it worked on eclipse. May i ask which ide are you using?

Comment: I found the reason. You are trying to add a string to `finalArray` but you initialize it as `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` on top.

Comment: I was trying to add add an ArrayList that would have a single element of an empty string. Anyways, I have edited my question to show the working code. Hope, it has no issues. Thanks for your help!